# Media Queried Div Drops Down to the Bottom of My Page at Specified Min-Width of 500px...Why?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to figure out why my div, which is CSS-styled by a **media query**, keeps **dropping to the bottom of the page when it stacks vertically at** `min-width: 500px`. The page consists of a centered background image and a box in the middle which houses three nested divs, which are boxes that will display three types of weather descriptions, respectively. Also, the text, **"Your Local Weather App"** drops below the box holding all the divs. I do not know why it does that either! Lastly how do I keep a gap between each box when they stack vertically?

Here is the link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/NwNOgq/

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="About">
      <h2>Your Local Weather App</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <div id="city">whatever
        </div >
        <div id="sky">whatever
        </div>
        <div id="windspeed">whatever
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.container{
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://s1.postimg.org/14i3xf2um7/Hummer-_H1-_Snow-_Turn-_Headlights-1024x768.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;  
}

.About{
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(650%)  
}

h2{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.holder{
  border: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .80);
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding:  10px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translateY(250%);    
  position: relative;  
}

#city, #sky, #windspeed{
  transform: translateY(9%);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom:2px inset #FFF;
  border-right:2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius:5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px ;
}

@media(min-width: 500px){
  .holder{display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's because you are adding `transform: translateY(250%)` to `.holder`. *Why* you are doing that, I'm not sure, as it's far more logical to use margins and padding for offsets. It's also unusual to opt for mobile-first development. What do you want to happen at less than 500px? Do you want it to stay the same? Then simply move your `grid-template-columns` out of your media query.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, mobile-first development, rather than desktop-first development is what they're saying is the best thing to do now....since the majority of people are using mobile devices to browse the internet. It also makes the web page load faster on the mobile device.  Mobile-first is a challenge...that I refuse to shy away from haha. But per your advice, let me try to see what will happen if I replace transform: translateY(250%) with something else though. And at less than 500px, I want the the three nested divs to stack up over each other, as you can see on the page.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, yeah, that transform: translateY(250%) was messing things up. Thankyou!! When I'm finish this weather app I'll get back to that other website that you helped me on. By the way, how do you format text in the comments? I see that you have done it here and I'm Interested!

Comment: No problem; glad to help! You use four tabs, or alternatively, highlight the code and press `CTRL + K`. For comments (like this), you'll need to put the text in backticks (below the tilde). You can also add a StackSnippet by clicking the code icon when creating a question. There's actually a **great** article on all formatting you can do [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Oh thankyou! Yay!! :D